# How to read an audio file from storage?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

I have some mp3 files in `IsolatedStorage` and want to play them.

I do this, but I don't hear anything:

```
IsolatedStorageFile isolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = isolatedStorage.OpenFile(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

musicMediaElement.SetSource(fileStream);
musicMediaElement.Play();
```

I think after opening file, I need to read it, but I don't know how?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this link.
this will shows you how to save and read the audio file from storage in windows phone.

**[Save and Read audio file from storage](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/74f20d/isolated-storage-to-save-and-read-mp3-file-from-windows-phon/)**

I hope you will get the solution.

Comment: thanks. I have followed it, but mine doesn't work.